# How do I get the value of the previous page a user has navigated to in a Frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm quite new to Stack so if this question needs improvements please tell me:

I'm creating a simple navigation app and I need to get the Page value of the previous page a user has navigated to.

I've implemented my own navigation system

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PageApp.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PageApp : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(PAGEFRAME.CanGoBack)
            PAGEFRAME.GoBack();
            
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the previous value of the page the user has navigated to. I want to store this in a list.

I have used WPF for over a year and it seems as though WPF is lacking in it's library of functions and properties in Frames and Navigation.

If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could store the page as soon as it is loaded/navigated to. Or are you only interested in the data of that page e.g. a form? Usually you don't need to access the history of the `Frame`. To navigate you also don't need a strong reference to the `Frame` itself. Just use a navigation method of  `Page.NavigationService`, which also exposes some useful events you might be interested in.

Comment: If you set `Frame.JournalOwnership` to `JournalOwnership.OwnsJournal`, you can use `NavigationService.GoBack` and `NavigationService.GoForward` to navigate through the prev/next content history. There shouldn't be a reason to maintain a custom navigation history.

Comment: @TomJoney: You somehow forgot to tell us how you navigate between pages. This is pretty central to be able to solve your issue.

Comment: @BionicCode , thank you for your comment sir: I will try this out.